# server tomcat v8.0 server at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, apache

I seem to have a problem with my web.xml file.
every time I run the Apache tomcat 8 server, it gives this error:
server tomcat v8.0 server at localhost failed to start.

when I removed the servlets of the xml file, the server worked!!
my web.xml is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ZiyadA00191914</display-name>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ListEventMainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.ListEventMainServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListEventMainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ListEventMainServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ListEventByCategory</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.ListEventByCategory</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListEventByCategory</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ListEventByCategory</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CartServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.CartServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CartServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CartServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>OrderServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.OrderServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>FeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.FeedbackServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FeedbackServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ShippingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.ShippingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShippingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShippingServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Driver.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>main.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>listEvents.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

any suggestion to get it working without removing code of the xml file ?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Can you keep one servlet and remove the rest to see if it is actually the servlets that are causing it or something else?

Comment: Paste the logs too

Answer (score 2):

one reason for this problem is the problems in web.xml file...

I also got this problem, i resolved it.

**Step to resolve this problem:**

1-  Check every servlet class name is correct(fully qualified class name )

2- for checking correct class name go on class name press ctrl and move the pointer on that class name if class name giving hyperlink then class name is correct otherwise you have to change with appropriate class name.

3- check jar you added in project are correct and working

4- after all this changes refresh the project and run it..

**it works....**

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml just add `<element> after "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"`
  and `add </element> after "</web-app>". It will work.`

Answer (score 0):

Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).
to solve following steps:

1. go to cmd
2. start Apache tomcat use this syntax(startup)
3. stop Apache tomcat use this syntax(shutdown)
4. go to eclipse start Apache tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this also (inexplicably, as web.xml had not changed).

This is what fixed it:

**Servers -> Tomcat V?.? Server at localhost -> [right click] -> clean -> OK**

Answer (score -1):

Go to 
File>>New>>Others>>Server>>Server
Create Server using the Latest Tomcat Version Available
If no server available you need to download and add the server.

Or the

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions could be using new instance of Server. This can be done by removing the existing one by going to server tab and right click >> delete server.
Now while adding a new server you will get an option saying "*Configure runtime environments..*", click on it and remove all the instances. Now are good to create new instance of server and deploy your servlet on server.